# Exporting png/svg as a single png file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, svg, export, png

So basically I have use SVG/javascript/PHP so that when a user clicks on a PNG image it takes the coordinates and uses these to plot a small black square on the PNG image, it's really very simple.

However, I was wondering if it's possible if you have the PNG in  tags within the SVG element, and the filled square on top of the PNG image (made using SVG 'rect'), to save this as 1 single PNG?

Comment: You could use canvas to draw the rect instead of svg. Then get the pixel data from the canvas and it would have the rect on it. If it is just a rect, you wouldn't have any benefit from using svg over canvas.

Comment: I don't have any particular need to use specifically SVG so am happy to try this (I originally was trying to use image maps!). The same applies with this though, how would one pull the pixel data from the canvas and save that image?

Comment: You should probably go through a simple canvas tutorial. I suggest checking the [Mozilla (mdn) tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial). Canvas isn't very hard to work with. For a quick idea of what you will need, check out [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes) about drawing a rectange and to save the image you can access the `canvasElement.toDataURL()` method to get a base64 encoded string of the image on the canvas. To save to user you can `location.href=dataURL` or ajax post it to a sever.

Comment: Added an answer so you can close this question since the comment pretty much answered what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably go through a simple canvas tutorial. I suggest checking the [Mozilla (mdn) tutorials‌​](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial). Canvas isn't very hard to work with. For a quick idea of what you will need, check out [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes) about drawing a rectange and to save the image you can access the `canvasElement.toDataURL()` method to get a base64 encoded string of the image on the canvas. To save to user you can `location.href=dataURL;` or post it to a sever using ajax.